# What are the ways to safely increment an integer?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Are there any other methods to make a thread-safe integer incrementation than using a synchronised method or an AtomicInteger?

Comment: why do you need any other way? AtomicInteger is your best bet as it doesn't hold lock so there's no risk or performance penalty as such. If you need more info in general about synchronization, probably this may help: http://java.dzone.com/articles/mind-it-synchronization-risky

Answer (score 1):

We have the following available synchronization options:

1) `volatile` (but it does not make ++ safe)

2) AtomicInteger (the best, it's lock free)

3) `synchronized`

4) java.util.concurrent.locks framework

So the third way is to use ReentrantLock

Comment: volatile helps if you access with a synch'd block

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize on a single object as well.

Example:

```
Integer myInteger = 0;
synchronized(myInteger) {
    myInteger += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because it's a read then a write.

You either have to use a locking mechanism (such as `synchronized`, but a `Lock` could be used just as well) or an atomic operation.